# Selecting roles from multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot

I have a table like this:

[image: Table]

As you can see studentId: 43 has two different GIDs (these are roles, with a max of 3).

I have to select the record like:

[image: Require]

Comment: So if a student has 3 roles, do you want 3 columns?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, supporting 3 GID types (and I added a student with 3 rows just to illustrate). You use the [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) operator to show each of up to 3 possible values on any student row. Not sure how a foreign key comes into play, though.

```
CREATE TABLE #like
(
  qsid      int identity(2,1),
  GID       tinyint,
  studentid int,
  userid    int
);

INSERT #like(GID, studentid, userid) VALUES
  (1,45,16),(2,43,16),(1,44,16),(3,46,16),
  (1,43,16),(1,47,16),(2,47,16),(3,47,16);

;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT
    studentid, 
    GID = CONVERT(varchar(11), GID),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentid ORDER BY GID)
  FROM #like
)
SELECT 
  [GID-TYPE-1] = [1],
  [GID-TYPE-2] = COALESCE([2], '-'),
  [GID-TYPE-3] = COALESCE([3], '-'),
  Student = studentid
FROM src 
PIVOT (MIN(GID) FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS p;
```

Results:

```
GID-TYPE-1  GID-TYPE-2  GID-TYPE-3  Student
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           -           43
1           -           -           44
1           -           -           45
3           -           -           46
1           2           3           47
```

If you only want the first two, and to ignore type 3 when both 1 and 2 also exist, just change it like so:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT
    studentid, 
    GID = CONVERT(varchar(11), GID),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentid ORDER BY GID)
  FROM #like
)
SELECT 
  [GID-TYPE-1] = [1],
  [GID-TYPE-2] = COALESCE([2], '-'),
  Student = studentid
FROM src 
PIVOT (MIN(GID) FOR rn IN ([1],[2])) AS p;
```